# What's the difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences() and getPreferences()?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm currently taking the "Developing Android Apps" Udacity course. In the "Lesson 3: New Activities and Intents >  Use SharedPreferences" segment, the instructor asked me to dig around the Android Developer site for how to get the user preferences from `SharedPreferences`. However, I found it different between the official documentation and the course's solution.

The Udacity course's [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yynDxu43pSM) says, to grab a `SharedPreferences` instance for the `PreferenceActivity`, you should call:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

(where `getActivity()` is simply the `Context` here because it's called inside a `Fragment`.)

While [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) on Android Developer Site indicates that you should call:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

So what's the difference between `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` and `Activity.getPreferences(int mode)`?

**Please note:** This question does not involve anything about `getSharedPreferences()` which requires a file name. It's about the difference between `getPreferences()` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25):

Acoording to the link you provided to Android documentation

> getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.
>
> getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your Activity, you don't supply a name.

So it is, use getSharedPreferences when the data you want to save/retrieve can be used from different activities in the app. If those preferences will only be used in one Activity, you can use getPreferences.

Edit: also note that as said in the post you linked 'getDefaultSharedPreferences will use a default name like "com.example.something_preferences", but getSharedPreferences will require a name'

Comment: the question did not address getsharedprefereces...  it was about the differences between getdefaultsharedpreference and getpreferences...  also note that if a preference key/value is stored using getshared preferences or getpreferences it will not be available as a default preference in another activity...  you know like the question asked about the differences between the things you didn't address...

Answer (score 16):

One of the major differences: getPreferences () returns a file only related to the activity it is opened from.  While getDefaultSharedPreferences () returns the application's global preferences.  Learned that the hard way yesterday.

Comment: Here you can find the relevant documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs

Comment: If I understand you correctly, calling `getPreferences()` in two different activities will result in two different files, right?

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look inside PreferenceManager:

```
public static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context),
            getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());
}

/**
 * Returns the name used for storing default shared preferences.
 *
 * @see #getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)
 * @see Context#getSharedPreferencesPath(String)
 */
public static String getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
}

private static int getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode() {
    return Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
}
```

So getDefaultSharedPreferences() use getSharedPreferences() method with your app package name and mode private, if you use getPreferences() from activity it will use the same getSharedPreferences() method but with getLocalClassName();

Answer (score 1):

From the first article linked below: "*Note: The SharedPreferences APIs are only for reading and writing key-value pairs and you should not confuse them with the Preference APIs, which help you build a user interface for your app settings (although they use SharedPreferences as their implementation to save the app settings).*"

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html